# How can I read zip file without saving to the disk with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

There are already many similar questions and tutorials available about this topic still I didn't found what I wanted to do.

I want to make an `API`, though which I can upload the zip file, that zip is containing xml files I am reading those files and sending the content as response.

The only problem here is currently I am storing the file inside of my project directory, but I don't want that I want to read the file directly without storing it in an directory.

So basically user will hit my API, upload the file and in response he will get the data present inside of files in that zip.

My Code:

```java
@RequestMapping(value ="/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
    File converFile = new File("src/main/"+file.getOriginalFilename());
    converFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(converFile);
    fout.write(file.getBytes());
    //unzipping file and reading data;
    String zipFileName = "src/main/"+file.getOriginalFilename();
    List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFileName));
    ZipEntry zipEntry;
    int read;
    while ((zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry())!= null) {
        while ((read = zis.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
            str.add(new String(buffer,0,read));
        }
    }
    while (zipEntry != null){
        zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
    }
    zis.closeEntry();
    zis.close();
    System.out.println("Unzip complete");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    System.out.println("List"+ str);

    fout.close();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(str, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This code is working fine uploading file saving it in project directory `(src/main)` and reading file data and giving the data as response.
How can I eliminate the saving part and do all these in code only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ByteArrayInputStream` instead of `FileInputStream`, like this:

```java
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes()));
```